# run java application with k8s and autoscaling with it's unique pod's property

Tags: docker, kubernetes, autoscaling

We have a requirement to run a standalone java application on docker with horizontal auto scaling capability with kubernetes. Main issue here is when each the pod gets created by auto scalling ability in K8S, each and every pod need to have its own properties to identify each process.This is due to each pod will operate on different data segments.Hope you understand the clarifications but i will provide further information if needed.

for Ex : Initially we start one pod it is assigned a property value say 'A'.

But if the second pod appears(after k8 scales to the 2nd one) it should automatically get the next property value B.

The data are segmented and categorised based on a label and need to know which pod pick the which data segment.

Thank you

Comment: i would suggest trying out the stateful sets which provide the unique name across the host. you can use the HPA along with the stateful set so each POD will get the unique hostname you can write the simple logic to find the hostname.

Comment: Just to make it clear, as far as I understood you've tried to run your pods as a `Deployment` so far, right ? As already mentioned above, choosing a `Statefulset` for such workload seems to be much better option.